# Why does a paragraph ending on a line break add an extra parskip?

Tags: parskip

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{eparskip} {
  \parindent0pt
  \setlength{\parskip}{1em}
}{
  \vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I know there's a stigma against adjusting the `parskip` parameter, but this behavior also happens with the parskip package itself.  Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third example ends with

```
<space><space>\vspace{1em}<bookkeeping business><space>\par
```

where the `<bookkeeping business>` is done by `\end{eparskip}` and is irrelevant to the issue.

The relevant thing is that the horizontal spaces before `\vspace` are not removed and make for a third line in the paragraph.

Where do they come from? The first one is from the end-of-line after `not`; the second is from the end-of-line before `\vspace` in the environment's definition. There's another one, coming from the end-of-line after `\end{eparskip}`, which comes before the `\par` generated by the blank line. This one is removed by `\par`, the others aren't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{eparskip}
 {\par\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}
 {\par\vspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no 
indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no 
indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no 
indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no 
indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be careful with line endings in definitions; also ensure that `\vspace` is issued *between* paragraphs, unless you have special needs.

Comment: This is great---thanks.  Do you mind elaborating on your comment about issuing `\vspace` *only* between paragraphs?  Specifically, what are some scenarios that you're presumably referring to be cautious about?

Answer (score 4):

the extra lines contain the spurious spaces you have added in the environment definition. Remove them and you get:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{eparskip} {%
  \parindent0pt
  \setlength{\parskip}{1em}%
}{%
  \par
  \vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\begin{eparskip}
The paragraphs in this block will have single space and no indent, and will not have weird spacing issues.
\end{eparskip}

\end{document}
```